# What is the configuration to make rabbitmq api and management plugin accessible from the web?

Tags: networking, configuration, rabbitmq

Trying to find a solution for opening RabbitMQ to the internet is not exactly easy. The documentation is sparse and the configuration I can find is in multiple formats. How can I configure RabbitMQ to allow external access?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to configure RabbitMQ: command line and two styles of configuration file. Here is how to configure RabbitMQ using one of the configuration styles.

First you'll need to find the rabbitmq.config. It is found in the RabbitMQ installation directory. I found mine here:

> C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config

The config file follows a very particular syntax. You'll need to take care. After a configuration change you will need to restart RabbitMQ for the configuration to take affect. If RabbitMQ stops immediately there is a problem with your configuration.

If RabbitMQ runs this only means that the configuration didn't kill the process. It does not mean that it was applied correctly. It will certainly apply if you get the syntax correctly, but every wrong configuration does not guarantee the service crashes.

**Follows are a few example configurations** (notice the trailing "**.**") :

1. **Base** of the RabbitMQ **configuration** style we will be using (should only appear once in the configuration file):

   ```
   [{rabbit, []}].
   ```
2. **Configuration** that allows the RabbitMQ **management plugin** to be accessed from the internet:

   ```
   [{rabbit,
     [ 
       {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 15672}]}]},
       {rabbitmq_management, [{cors_allow_origins, ["*"]}]}
     ]
   }].
   ```
3. **Configuration** that allows the RabbitMQ **api** to be accessed from the internet:

   ```
   [{rabbit,
     [ 
       {tcp_listeners, [5672]}
     ]
   }].
   ```
4. **Configuration** that allows **guest user** to access the management plugin from the internet:

   ```
   [{rabbit,
     [ 
       {loopback_users, []},
       {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 15672}]}]},
       {rabbitmq_management, [{cors_allow_origins, ["*"]}]}
     ]
   }].
   ```
5. **Configuration** that does all of the above:

   ```
   [{rabbit,
     [ 
       {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
       {loopback_users, []},
       {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 15672}]}]},
       {rabbitmq_management, [{cors_allow_origins, ["*"]}]}
     ]
   }].
   ```

Leaving a trailing comma in an array in your configuration will cause RabbitMQ to stop.

If you are still having issues check that you've permitted the ports through any firewalls.

**Considerations** This leaves your RabbitMQ server wide open. You will want to certainly restrict the access. A search of **tcp_listeners** will reveal other options to restrict access to particular ip. It is also not a good idea to expose the default **guest user** to the internet in any production environment.